# XSL how to process child elements separately?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to render the non-nested part of xml separately from the nested part.  E.g is it possible to render this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="para.xsl"?>
<paragraph>Introduction
  <list> 
   <element>First</element>
   <element>Second</element>
  </list>
</paragraph>
```

as

```
<p>Introduction
<ul>
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

?

My stylesheet (which doesn't work) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph"  >
  <p><xsl:value-of select="*[not(list)]"/></p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="list" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list"  >
  <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="element"/></ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element"  >
  <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet >
```

It renders as

```
<p> 
   First
   Second
  </p>
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that neither in HTML 4 nor in HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) a `p` element is allowed to contain a block element like an `ul` element so while XSLT can easily create the tree you asked for the browser's HTML parser is likely to finish the `p` element when it encounters the `ul` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to render the non-nested part of xml separately from the
>   nested part.

There is no problem with nesting as this is taken care of the **[XSLT processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Processing-Model)** and the **[XSLT built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)** -- read more on these topics or watch an **[XSLT training course](http://app.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1)**. You only need to override the built-in templates as shown below.

---

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list">
   <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
   <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```